# Invoking the Laravel Validation from the clients end

Tags: javascript, laravel

Is there a way to use an identical validation algorithm on the client side as to the one used in Laravel backend. I'm trying to represent the validation state to the user before they submit the form.

That way there will be no doubts about passing one test and failing the other and giving the end-user unreliable information.

The Laravel validation method I'm using is

```
$this->validate($request, [
```

I'm aware I could post the value to backend function every time a form state changes via AJAX. But I would guess that doing that for each change would be a little to resource consuming, and doing it when the user leaves the form would be better but still a little two much. Please correct me if i'm wrong.
Thanks for any input, its appreciated!

Comment: You mean to say that you want to do an additional validation, aside from the one you perform using the Laravel validator? If so, the question is: why?

Comment: @Bogdan because I want to represent the state of the validation to the user before they submit the form.

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Why not just implement a javascript library and validate it via client and once javascript says its valid, revalidate it on backend ?

Comment: @Theodor B what do you mean by via client

Comment: Client means front end, like validating it via javascript.

Comment: I recommend you http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

So, in Laravel 5, you can do validation before your data gets into controller.

Things you have to do: (Simple Eg. for State level entry validation)

> 1. Create a file in `app/Http/Request\Validator`, name it as StateValidationRequest.php
> 2. Inside it write this code snippet:

```
    use App\Http\Requests\Request;

    class StateValidationRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(){
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Required|Regex:/^[a-zA-Z\(\)\'\.\s]+$/i|Max:100|Unique:loc_states,name,' . Request::segment(2) . ',_id',
            'country' => 'Required',
            'state_code' => 'alpha',
            'is_active' => 'Required|Boolean',
            'country_id' => 'Exists:loc_countries,_id',
            'revision' => 'numeric'
        ];
    }

    public function messages(){
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Name is required',
            'name.unique' => 'State name should be unique',
            'country.required' => 'Country is required',
            'state_code.alpha' => 'Code must be entirely alphabetic characters',
            'name.regex' => 'Allowed characters for name are a-z (lowercase and capital), brackets \'(\' and \')\', single quote \', dot (.) and space ( )',
            'is_active.required' => 'State must be set to either active or in-active',
            'country_id.exists' => 'Kindly select a valid country',
            'revision.numeric' => 'Revision must be numeric'
        ];
     }
    }
```

> 3. (Last) In your controller (where you want validation)

Write this (on the top and below namespace):

```
use App\Http\Requests\Validator\StateValidationRequest;
```

and, this in your store/update function

```
public function store(StateValidationRequest $stateValidator){

}
```

If there is any kind of validation error, it will redirect to the register page. See, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use [parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) for example, it's a JS validation library. But there are others. I agree with you that using laravel validator each time your user ends up filling a field would be incredibly resourceful so in my opinion don't do it.

Doing JS validation works very well in some case but can be more difficult and time consuming to implement. If you are working on a form with only few input fields and simple validation rule, doing a JS validation is ok , and it 's maybe more user friendly.